# Given a lat/long, what's the simplest way to retrieve the city and state using JSONP?

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, geolocation

I am looking for an API. Preferably a JSONP API (client side)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a JSONP but you can manipulate this as you want. I am using Google Map API client-side.

```
var lat = 'some value';
   var lng = 'some value'; 
   geomap.geocode({'latLng':new google.map.latLng(lat,lng)},function(res){
            var tmp = [];
            $.each(res,function(i,e){
                    if(e.address_components.length>=4){
                            tmp.push(e);
                    }
            });
            if(tmp.length>=1){      
                    tmp.sort();
                    $.each(tmp[0].address_components,function(i,e){
                            if(e.types=='postal_code')  console.log(e.short_name);
                            if(e.types[0]=='administrative_area_level_1') console.log(e.short_name);
                            if(e.types[0]=='locality') console.log(e.short_name);
                    });
            }
    });
```